# Spectral Measures: Scale Embeddings

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}N\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

And its spectral measure:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad N=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$$

Construct scale functions:
$$\Lambda_s:=\sqrt{1+|\mathrm{id}|^2}^s\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})$$

As well as scale norms:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N):\quad\|\varphi\|_s:=\|\Lambda_s(N)\varphi\|$$

And the scale spaces:
$$\mathcal{H}_s:=\overline{\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N)}^s:=\widehat{\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N)}^s$$

Regard the embeddings:
$$\iota:\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N)\hookrightarrow\mathcal{D}\Lambda_{s-\varepsilon}(N)\quad(\varepsilon>0)$$

> Then one obtains:
>   $$\|\overline{\iota}\|\leq1:\quad\mathcal{N}\overline{\iota}=(0)\quad\overline{\mathcal{R}\overline{\iota}}^{s-\varepsilon}=\mathcal{H}^{s-\varepsilon}$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: **ATTENTION:** Note that the problem has been extended drastically!! **(The previous answer was fully correct!)*

Comment: 12 edits in a relatively short span raise an eyebrow again. Were they necessary?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Woow really 12??? Yaa, I edited until I was satisfied with the presentation of the subject. But I'll try to use more sandbox!! *(Besides, more or less I'm fine with it now.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Special thanks to T.A.E.!!*

**Solution**

They are contractive:
$$\|\iota(\varphi)\|_{s-\varepsilon}^2=\int\Lambda_{s-\varepsilon}^2\mathrm{d}\nu_\varphi\leq\int\Lambda_s^2\mathrm{d}\nu_\varphi=\|\varphi\|_s^2$$

For positive scales:*
$$s\geq0:\quad\overline{\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N)}=\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N)\implies\mathcal{N}\overline{\iota}=\mathcal{N}\iota=(0)$$

For negative scales:**
$$s<0:\quad\mathcal{N}\overline{\iota}=\mathcal{N}\left(\overline{\Lambda_{-s}}\circ\overline{\iota}\circ\overline{\Lambda_s}\right)=(0)$$

They have dense range:
$$\mathcal{H}^{s-\varepsilon}=\overline{\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N)}^{s-\varepsilon}=\overline{\iota(\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N))}^{s-\varepsilon}\\
=\overline{\overline{\iota}(\mathcal{D}\Lambda_s(N))}^{s-\varepsilon}\subseteq\overline{\overline{\iota}(\mathcal{H}^s)}^{s-\varepsilon}\subseteq\mathcal{H}^{s-\varepsilon}$$

Concluding the assertion.

**Remark**

Injectivity is nontrivial: [Embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357161/79762)

**See the thread: [Scale Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1348643/79762)*

***See the thread [Scale Operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1348744/79762)*

Answer (score 1):

The spaces $E[-a,a]\mathcal{H}$, $0 < a < \infty$ are contained in and dense in every scale space.

Comment: Ah of course... I guess you mean their union is a core for any of these?

Comment: @Freeze_S : That's right. For PDEs this normally works out to be a class of infinitely differentiable functions; that's a natural effect of filtering out out the higher spectral components. (It's like truncating the Inverse Fourier transform to a finite interval.)

Comment: Hello T.A.E. I couldn't check injectivity. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Also would you mind if I add my attempt above??? *(I'd be really happy about it.)*

Comment: Sorry for unchecking your answer. I will check yours again, of course! *(People just might get irritated.)*