# Embedding: Extension

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

**Problem**

Given Banach spaces $E_0$ and $E$

Regard dense domain:
$$\overline{\mathcal{D}_0}=E_0\quad\overline{D}=E$$

Consider an embedding:
$$\Phi:\mathcal{D}_0\hookrightarrow\mathcal{D}:\quad\|\Phi(\varphi)\|\leq\|\varphi\|_0$$

Then one is tempted:
$$\overline{\Phi}:E_0\hookrightarrow E:\quad\|\overline{\Phi}(\varphi)\|\leq\|\varphi\|_0$$

Does this really follow?*

**I mean injectivity.*

**Reference**

I'm trying to check: [Embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193817/79762)

Comment: Since the function is uniformly continuous then we can extend it on the comletion metric space to a continuous mapping. It remains to prove that it is linear. A feeling exists that this a routine matter.

Comment: Yes but does it remain injective???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thanks alot to T.A.E.!!*

**Counterexample**

Given the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}_0)$.

Consider the domain:
$$\mathcal{D}_0:=\langle\{e_0+\frac{1}{n}e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\rangle$$

It is dense since:
$$e_0=\lim_n(e_0+\frac{1}{n}e_n):\quad e_0\in\overline{\mathcal{D}_0}\Rightarrow e_n\in\overline{\mathcal{D}_0}$$

Define the operator:*
$$L_0:\mathcal{D}_0\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N}_0):\quad (L\varphi)(k):=\varphi(k+1)$$

Then it is contractive:
$$\|L_0\varphi\|=\|L\varphi\|\leq\|\varphi\|$$

And it is injective:
$$e_0\notin\mathcal{D}_0\implies\mathcal{N}L_0=(0)$$

But for its closure it is:
$$\overline{L_0}e_0=Le_0=0$$

That gives a counterexample!

**Nothing but left-shift!*

**Reference**

See the thread: [Construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/819581/79762)